# How to do a constrain in Gurobi

Tags: python, constraints, gurobi

I have a constrain i dont know how to do in gurobi if someone can help me
[image]

[image]

This is what i try in the first but i dont know if is correct

```
T = range(25)
TL = range(21)
X=model.addVars(E,T,S,vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="X")
model.addConstrs((quicksum(X[e,t,s] for t  in T) <= 3 for e in E for t in TL for s in S), name="R4")
```

For the second i try but it send me a error

```
T = range(25)
S = range(10)
X=model.addVars(E,T,S,vtype=GRB.BINARY, name="X")
model.addConstrs((quicksum(X[e,t,s] for t in T for s in S) <= T* Z[e] for e in E), name="R6")
```

The error

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'range' and 'Var'

Answer (score 0):

You just need to replace `T` with `len(T)` to get the desired result. You cannot multiply a range with a variable for a right-hand side value.

```
model.addConstrs((quicksum(X[e,t,s] for t in T for s in S) <= len(T) * Z[e] for e in E), name="R6")
```